# What is the correct way to hang up a video call in vLine?

Tags: vline

I am currently using `Client.stopMediaSessions()`. Is this correct? From what I read in the documentation, and see in the examples, this seems to be the right way to do it.

This should stop both local and remote streams, correct?

What event(s) is/are fired when `stopMediaSessions()` is called? From my logs, it doesn’t seem that the handler for `mediaStream:end` is being called. Should it be? Or is `enterState:closed` the only event fired? Or are both fired?

My question has to do with removing the `<video>` elements from the DOM – both for the remote and local elements. In your example for `MediaStream` in the `API Reference`, the `addStream()` function handles both `mediaStream:start` and `mediaStream:end` events. However, when using this to add both local and remote streams, you can’t count on the `mediaElement` variable in the `mediaStream:end` handler because nothing ties that var to the stream, so you don’t know which element to do a `removeChild()` on.

Anyway, that’s not a big deal. I am just curious what the sequence of events is when a `stopMediaSessions()` is called; from that I can ensure the right `<video>` element is being removed.

But in general, I do want to know what the correct way is to hang up/terminate a video call among a set of participants.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`client.stopMediaSessions()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client#stopMediaSessions) will stop **all** [`vline.MediaSessions`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession) for the given [`vline.Client`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client), so yes, it will "hang up" a call.

To "hang up" an audio/video session with a specific user ([`vline.Person`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Person)), you can use [`Person.stopMedia()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#stopMedia).

A [`vline.MediaSession`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession) can have local and remote [`vline.MediaStreams`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream) associated with it, so by stopping a `vline.MediaSession` you will implicitly stop all `vline.MediaStreams` associated with it.

Since `client.stopMediaSessions()` is stopping all of the `vline.MediaSession`'s (and therefore `vline.MediaStream`'s), you should get both a `mediaStream:end` event (from the `vline.MediaStream`) and a `enterState:closed` event (from the `vline.MediaSession`).

For adding and removing `<video>` elements and keeping track of them, I'd suggest doing something similar to what the [vLine shell example](https://github.com/vline/shell-example) does. It uses the unique MediaStream ID to name the `div` that it puts the `<video>` element in:

```js
mediaSession.on('mediaSession:addLocalStream mediaSession:addRemoteStream', function(event) {
  var stream = event.stream;

  // guard against adding a local video stream twice if it is attached to two media sessions
  if ($('#' + stream.getId()).length) {
    return;
  }

  $('#video-wrapper').append(elem);
 });

// add event handler for remove stream events
mediaSession.on('mediaSession:removeLocalStream mediaSession:removeRemoteStream', function(event) {
  $('#' + event.stream.getId()).remove();
});
```

Comment: Tom, one comment: the `getId()` method is not defined anywhere in the `API reference`, so there's no way of knowing about it unless you implement (or study carefully) the examples. This sounds like a useful function, so perhaps at some point you could add some doco to it in your `API Reference`.

Comment: @Lew The documentation should now be [updated](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream#getId)